# How can I transfer videos from a DV cam to a computer?

Tags: drivers

I have an old Sony DV cam with recordings on DV cartridges whose video content I would like to transfer to my desktop PC.

What do I need to transfer them?
How is the process like?

Comment: @DavidPostill You jumped the gun here. They're looking for a driver, not a purchase. Sony discontinued the driver, so it will be hard to locate it, possibly through archive.org, or a site that offers it, such as https://www.helpdrivers.com/cameras/Sony/DCR-HC_Serie/DCR-HC35E/.

Comment: Also, consider buying a device that can take your cassette and transfer it to a pc. Either a cassette to vcr adapter with a vcr to usb capture device, or something similar.

Comment: Also maybe https://archive.org/details/ImageMixer

Comment: I rewrote the question in a generalized manner assuming that the answer to this particular question would answer the more specific question of the thread starter as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest FireWire as the method. (Sony calls it "i.LINK", but it's the same thing.) It may take some effort to assemble the obsolete hardware needed, but there is a standard way to connect a DV camera through FireWire so a driver shouldn't be needed – it works the same with any camera supporting it – and you can get a high-quality digital dump of what's on the DV tape, without any signal degradation.

Equipment needed:

- PC with a FireWire port. I'm pretty sure I've seen PCI-Express cards adding one to a desktop PC (though mine are for traditional PCI, from eBay), and Apple used to have FireWire800-to-Thunderbolt adapters for more modern systems. There aren't any for plain USB though.
- A suitable cable to connect the camera's "i.LINK" port to the PC's FireWire port (note that FW400 and FW800 use very different connectors).
- Linux system (e.g. a live CD/USB – not WSL or VM) with the `dvgrab` program installed. There certainly are FireWire DV grabbers for Windows as well, but dvgrab seemed to be a "run it and forget" tool.
- Some patience, as the transfer is at 1x speed. (The camera literally "plays" the whole tape during the process.)

It's certainly not the easiest or cheapest option, but it's *an* option.

Comment: Thank YOU All so much for taking the time to help me, especially  for the Driver link. But Despite installing the Driver through the compatibility assistance its still not being recognized it was previous working fine in Windows XP in 2009 When I try on my media laptop which does not connect to the internet and is running Windows 7 it locks halfway through installation of the Driver. SONY Were NO HELP Sending an outdated link (404) error to BUY a copy of the Driver ! Once again THANK YOU All Again for trying to help.